# React hook form subscribing to the changes issue

Tags: reactjs, performance, react-hook-form

Good evening!
I am struggling with react hook form performance.
In the official guide they are saying that to subscribe to state changes you should deconstruct the form state like follows.

```
const { dirtyFields } = useFormState()
```

But doing so every component that uses `useFormContext` inside rerenders when the subscription changes. In this case if any field inside a form (imagine a huge form) becomes dirty every element that uses `useFormContext` rerenders and you cannot stop it.

```
const ExampleOfComponent = () => {
    const a = useFormContext()
    return <>Test</>
}
```

### Sandbox

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-radio-example-forked-36xo8j?file=/src/App.tsx:570-581) to illustrate what I am talking about.
To reproduce make dirty the input A and notice that the input B rerenders also because the `useFormContext()` inherits in such way the subscription. Notice that I am deconstructing the `dirtyFields` only for illustrative purpose without using it.

### react hook form article

This is the react hook form [article](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/formstate) that in the rules section explains why we should deconstruct the formstate.

### Question

Is there any way to use the state in a more performant way? If I need to use the staff of useFormState what happens if I not deconstruct? How can I block the rerender of all the components that are using useFormContext in order to rerender them only if the relevant data was changed?
I am missing some best practice or is a lack of the library?

Comment: Hi, did you have any luck getting this resolved?  I'm facing a similar issue.

Comment: The issue about the performance is due to the context propagation of the form context. To have a better understanding of how the context affects your performances take a look at this article https://react-hook-form.com/advanced-usage/ under Form provider Performance section. Unfortunately when you use a framework like react admin that abuse a little bit of the context (trade-off of simplicity) this is unresolvable. Hope that this will help you! @MarkP